# Conditional expectation of a Gaussian given a r.v.?

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation, expected-value

Let $X$ be a standard Gaussian random variable and $B$ a standard Bernoulli random variable. Let $Y = B \cdot X$.

Computing $E(Y\mid X)$ is rather straightforward. I simply substitute $Y = B \cdot X$ and apply independence of  $X$ and $B$, obtaining $\frac{X}{2}$ .

But **how to compute $E(X\mid Y)$?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $E(X\mid Y)=Y$. Here are two solutions, depending on which level of probability theory you are studying.

---

**1<sup>st</sup> Way.** We know that $E(X\mid Y)=u(Y)$, where $u(y)=E(X\mid Y=y)$. So we only need to determine the function $u(y)$. But

1. If $y = 0$, then
   $$E(X\mid Y=0)=E(X\mid B=0\text{ or } X=0).$$
   Since $P(B=0)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $P(X=0)=0$, we may neglect the contribution from the condition $X=0$ and write
   $$=E(X\mid B=0)=E(X)=0$$
   where the second step follows from the independence.
2. If $y \neq 0$, then
   $$E(X\mid Y=y)=E(X\mid B=1\text{ and }X=y)=E(X\mid X=y)=y,$$
   where the second step follows from the independence again.

Altogether, we get $u(y)=y$ and hence

> $$E(X\mid Y)=Y.$$

---

**2<sup>nd</sup> Way.** We know that $E(X\mid Y)$ is the $P$-a.s. unique random variable $Z$ which is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable and satisfies

$$ E(X\mathbf{1}_A) = E(Z\mathbf{1}_A), \qquad \forall A \in \sigma(Y). \tag{*}$$

Now we claim that

> $$E(X\mid Y)=Y, \qquad P\text{-a.s.}$$

This amounts to showing that $\text{(*)}$ holds with the choice $Z = Y$. Since the events of the form $\{Y\leq y\}$ generates $\sigma(Y)$, it suffices to check $\text{(*)}$ only for this form of events by the [Monotone Class Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem#Monotone_class_theorem_for_functions). Now,

1. If $y < 0$, then $\{Y \leq y\} = \{B=1, X\leq y\}$ and hence
   $$ X\mathbf{1}_{\{Y\leq y\}} = BX\mathbf{1}_{\{Y\leq y\}} = Y\mathbf{1}_{\{Y\leq y\}} .$$
   This then shows that
   $$ E[X\mathbf{1}_{\{Y\leq y\}}] = E[Y\mathbf{1}_{\{Y\leq y\}}]. $$
2. If $y \geq 0$, then $\{Y \leq y\} = \{B=1, X\leq y\} \cup \{B = 0\}$, and so,
   $$ X\mathbf{1}_{\{Y\leq y\}} = X\mathbf{1}_{\{B=1, X\leq y\}} + X\mathbf{1}_{\{B = 0\}} .$$
   Similarly as before, the first term can be treated as
   \begin{align*}
   X\mathbf{1}_{\{B=1, X\leq y\}}
   &= BX\mathbf{1}_{\{B=1, X\leq y\}} \\
   &= Y\mathbf{1}_{\{B=1, X\leq y\}} \\
   &= Y\mathbf{1}_{\{B=1, X\leq y\}} + Y\mathbf{1}_{\{B=0\}} \\
   &= Y\mathbf{1}_{\{Y \leq y\}},
   \end{align*}
   where the third step follows from $ Y\mathbf{1}_{\{B=0\}} = 0 $. In light of this, we get
   \begin{align*}
   E[X\mathbf{1}_{\{Y\leq y\}}]
   &= E[Y\mathbf{1}_{\{Y \leq y\}}] + E[X\mathbf{1}_{\{B=0\}}] \\
   &= E[Y\mathbf{1}_{\{Y \leq y\}}] + E[X]P(B = 0) \\
   &= E[Y\mathbf{1}_{\{Y \leq y\}}].
   \end{align*}

Therefore the desired conclusion follows.

Comment: Thank you, really clear answer! Just one little clarification. I didn't understand how can we use independence to prove this step $E(X\mid B=1\text{ and }X=y)=E(X\mid X=y)$... ?

Comment: @Robb1, It requires some justification, but it is basically an analogy with the following probability version: if $A$, $B$, $C$ are events and $C$ is independent from both $A$ and $B$, then $$P(A\mid B\cap C)=P(A\mid B),$$ provided $P(B\cap C)>0$. However, I realized that a much simpler explanation is available: $$E(X\mid B=1, X=y)=E(y\mid B=1,X=y)=y.$$